# I have a rich text editor, but displaying the information is what isnt right

Tags: html

I have a rich text editor. 
This is how the information when into the database

```
<p>Hello,</p>

<p>asdfasdfsdfsafdsfdsadf</p>

<p><img alt="smiley" src="http://www.bettergamerzunited.com/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/regular_smile.png" style="height:23px; width:23px" title="smiley" /></p>
```

How do I get it to echo what the right way, How do I echo the information but still have the intergaty of the html tags.

Because this is the information on the website.

```
    <p>Hello,</p>

<p>asdfasdfsdfsafdsfdsadf</p>

<p><img alt="smiley" src="http://www.bettergamerzunited.com/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/regular_smile.png" style="height:23px; width:23px" title="smiley" /></p>
```

Comment: It's the same? Except for the tab-character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are outputting the data as the value of a `textarea` element which then gets converted with JavaScript to the rich text editor, the you might want to make sure you don't echo it on a new line, because the `textarea` value will include the extra tabs or spaces right after the opening tag.

So if your code looks like this:

```
<textarea>
   {variable_output_goes_here}
</textarea>
```

It should instead be like this:

```
<textarea>{variable_output_goes_here}</textarea>
```